# What's holding up my ByteBuffer from freeing?

Tags: java, memory, bytebuffer

I'm allocating a lot of byte buffers.  After I'm done with them I set all reference to null.  This is supposedly the "correct" way to release bytebuffers?  Dereference it and let the GC clean it up ?  I also call System.gc() to try and help it along.

Anyways, I create a bunch of buffers, deference them; but after "some time" I get all sorts of memory errors: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

I can increase the MaxDirectMemorySize but it just delays the above error.

I'm 99% positive I don't have anything referencing the old ByteBuffers.  Is there a way to check this to see what the heck still has a ByteBuffer allocated?

Comment: References to supposedly unreferenced data structures often hide out in the collection classes. Other places include listeners and other inner class constructs. I'd check those places first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like MAT that's free with Eclipse to see what is keeping your byte buffer by letting it do some heapdump analysis.

Another way I can think of is to wrap your byte buffer with something else that has a finalizer method.

Also Systen.gc() does not guarantee that finalizers will be executed you need to do     System.runFinalization() to increase the likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the references to null is the correct way to let the garbage collector that you are finished with that object.  There must still be some other dangling reference.  The best tool I have found for finding memory leaks is [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com).  A free alternative that is also very good is [Visual VM from the JDK](http://visualvm.java.net).

Remember that the slice() operation creates a new byte buffer that references the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with older versions of Java.  The latest version of Java 6 will call System.gc() before throwing an OutOfMemoryError.  If you don't want to trigger a GC you can release the direct memory manually on the Oracle/Sun JVM with

```
((DirectBuffer) buffer).cleaner().clean();
```

However, it is a better approach to recycle the direct buffers yourself so doing this is not so critical. (Creating direct ByteBuffers is relatively expensive)

Answer (score 0):

Direct `java.nio.ByteBuffer` is (by definition) stored outside of java heap space. It is not freed until GC runs on heap, and frees it. But you can imagine a situation where heap usage is low therefore it does not need GC, but non-heap memory gets allocated and runs out of bounds.

Based on very interesting read:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-nativememory-linux/

> The pathological case would be that the native heap becomes full and
>   one or more direct ByteBuffers are eligible for GC (and could be freed
>   to make some space on the native heap), but the Java heap is mostly
>   empty so GC doesn't occur.